# pyinstaller can stop working correctly

Tags: pyinstaller

Recently, I added a sub-directory and few script files with an empty **init**.py in the new sub-directory. There is no **init**.py in foo_main_dir.

```
 foo_main_dir
    |
    |---- main.py
    ----- foo_sub_dir
          |
          ---- foo.py
```

Sometimes pyinstaller stoped working completely after I made some changes in foo.sub.dir with an import error at run-time of the executable file:

ImportError: No module named foo

```
Due to main.py import:
    from foo_main_sub.foo import FOO
```

None of .pyc was generated in both directories.
A workaround is to reinstall pyinstller. It is quite annoying.

Appreciate if you know a permanent solution.